# http://localhost/ now working in browser mac

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, localhost, apache-http-server

in snow leapord machine `http://localhost/` isn't working through browser. But when I ping `http://localhost/` I do get successful replies

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.151 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.101 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.095 ms
```

Error log show something like below

```
(2)No such file or directory: httpd: could not open error log file /usr/\xe2\x80\x9c/private/var/log/apache2/phpMyAdmin.localhost-error_log\xe2\x80\x9d. Unable to open logs
```

what might be wrong?

Comment: What happens if you do `http://127.0.0.1/`?

Comment: same not working

Comment: What error message do you get in the browser?

Comment: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost

Comment: Silly question: is apache2 started and listening on port 80?

Comment: how do I check that? if its not, how do I start it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running the following command:

```
netstat -an -p tcp | grep 80 | grep LISTEN
```

you should get a line like this one :

```
tcp4       0      0  *.80                   *.*                    LISTEN
```

If you don't, your server is not started, whatever the reason is.

If you are trying to access is your Web sharing, check the System settings -> Sharing -> Personal Web Sharing is active.

Comment: I can't see anything. how do I fix this?

Comment: What do you expect to find when you access http://localhost ?

Did you check that "Personal web sharing" is active ?

Comment: yes it is active. I expect to see `It Works` message. Actually I am trying to setup phpmuadmin

Comment: From your error string i woulg guess that you weongly copied and pasted left and right quotation marks ( like “,” or «,») when setting up phpmyadmin. Did you check that?

Answer (score 1):

The error log reveals that `\xe2\x80\x9c` appears twice in the path. That means that you have used `”` rather than `"` in your path, which will not be interpreted correctly.

Replace them both with " instead and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Successful pinging indicates the target machine is online (and has ICMP ping reply on). Clearly it is, since you're pinging your own machine (that's what `localhost` or 127.0.0.1 is).

Opening `http://localhost/` in a browser will only work if there's a web server running on port 80 on the target machine (in this case, localhost, is your own machine). You probably do not have a web server running, do you? If it you do, it must be off or misconfigured.

Comment: how do I check if web-server is running and if not running how do I start it

Comment: I tried stoping and restarting web server with `apachectl stop` and `apachectl start` command but still not working

Comment: How to check if a web-server is running depends on the web-server.

Which web-server did you install? Did you try following the instructions they've laid out for getting started?

Comment: the that comes with snow leopard, i guess its apache web server

Answer (score 0):

I found these two things were necessary on Snow Leopard:

1. Make sure that /etc/apache2/httpd.conf has a proper entry for "UserDir" [ grep UserDir /etc/apache2/httpd.conf ].  What I needed was:  UserDir Sites  [ I assume you know how to use Terminal.app and "sudo" commands.]
2. If you have your own firewall, make sure 127.0.0.1 is allowed for port 22, such as: "allow tcp from 127.0.0.1 to any dst-port 22 in". I also recommend: "allow tcp from any to any dst-port 80 in".